# Java synchronization tool unlock once use unlimited times

Tags: java, synchronization, locking

I want an object that can be

1. locked once by any thread (no ownership!)
2. requested an arbitrary number of times resulting in block (block only if locked)
3. unlocked once by any thread (again, no ownership)
4. all requesting (blocked) threads (including future requests yet to be made!) are no longer blocked

This seems like it would be akin to a semaphore except with infinite permits once unlocked.

Is this possible in Java? How it be accomplished?

Comment: It looks like, you're working on multithreading. All thread will try to get same data, after that each thread will get the own data one by one for processing, and when you finish you don't want to process it again. Is it correct your purpose ?

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing what problem this would be used to solve. `Semaphore` does have `drainPermits()` and `release(int)` which could be used to mimic this, but I wouldn't go down that route just yet.

Comment: @BIZ I don't think so. I have many threads being created or reused. They are processing requests of various types (lets call these types B & C), but need to wait (block) to process a specific type of request.  There is a second type of request (let's call it A) that makes it acceptable for the waiting threads (and any new ones) to process their requests of type B or C. Anytime after A, B & C are okay.

Comment: @Kayaman I am in a servlet environment across a distributed network of nodes sending messages to each other to perform various distributed algorithms. It is important that some of these messages wait to be processed until some condition is met. The number and timing of the messages that may need to wait is not knowable in each node. Therefore a means is needed to allow an arbitrary number of threads in a node to block. Also, the condition that needs to be met may occur in any thread so ownership can't be enforced (as it is in a ReadWriteLock).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
public class GateLock {
    private boolean isOpen;
    public GateLock() {
        isOpen = false;
    }

    public synchronized void open(){
        isOpen = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void close(){
        isOpen = false;
    }

    public synchronized void enter(){
        while(!isOpen) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```